# Loss of precision

Tags: java, precision

I tried running the following code:

```
double f = 4.35; 
int n = (int) (100 * f);
```

`n` will be `434`. Why?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.35 cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number since .35 is not a (negative) power of 2.  As a result, there's a bit of roundoff one way or another.  There will probably also be roundoff when you multiply by 100.  If the resulting number is a bit less than 435, casting to int will take the floor of it, which is 434.

If you'd like to round to the NEAREST integer, you can add 0.5 to the result and then cast to int.  This is the most general way to round numbers, although Java has a built-in implementation of rounding.

```
double f = 4.35; 
int n = (int) (100 * f + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch this. I made first year uni students watch it for homework. http://vimeo.com/7403673 - Jon Skeet and Tony the Pony.

Jon Skeet's presentation at the London Stack Overflow DevDays event: stackoverflow.carsonified.com

At around 6:50 he talks about maths in Java and some of the common problems faced by developers with regards to maths.

Comment: Not an answer without some kind of summary.

Comment: I would have downvoted your answer if I hadn't found the video so interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
double f = 4.35; 
int n = (int) Math.round(100 * f);
```

Now `n` will have as value `435`, as expected. This kind of problems happen because of rounding errors when dealing with decimal values represented in base 2, take a look at this reference to find out more: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is because floating point numbers are internally represented in base 2 not base 10.

this here will help (have to import `Math`):

```
double f = 4.35; 
long n = Math.round(100 * f);
```